# HTML5 Canvas: Elements drawn with/cached for drawImage are smoothed when scaled and/or moved

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I do know about the case of float/integer values for `drawImage`'s `x` and `y`. But what I need is a smooth animation with an ability to cache my shapes.

- [Article on caching complex paths with backup canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20161213040833/http://simonsarris.com/blog/427-increasing-performance-by-caching-paths-on-canvas)
- [Article on `drawImage` with float parameters](http://sebleedelisle.com/2011/02/html5-canvas-sprite-optimisation/)

For example, I want to draw some complex shape (i.e. SVG-tiger, [converted to canvas-commands](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/awesome_tiger.html)) to canvas just once and then move it *smoothly* with `ctx.translate` and `ctx.drawImage`. I need the float values then, because instead I get a step-by-step moving:

Here's the examples at JSFiddle:

- [One](http://jsfiddle.net/KYZYT/3/): Fast speed, with `Math.floor` applied to `translate` parameters (`x` and `y` are equal to time in seconds multiplied by `10`): Animation is weird (sequential, not smooth).
- [Two](http://jsfiddle.net/KYZYT/6/): Slow speed, with `Math.floor` applied to `translate` parameters (`x` and `y` are equal to time in seconds): Animation is weird (sequential, not smooth).
- [Three](http://jsfiddle.net/KYZYT/4/): Fast speed, no rounding, float values (`x` and `y` are equal to time in seconds multiplied by `10`). Speed is fast, so animation looks good.
- **[Four](http://jsfiddle.net/KYZYT/5/)**: Slow speed, no rounding, float values (`x` and `y` are equal to time in seconds). Speed is slow, so animation looks *pulsating*. **Why?**

The last case is the one that confuses me. Am I wrong in my tryings and there is a possibility to make this caching trick work nice?

In Firefox, there is a property of canvas named `mozImageSmoothingEnabled` ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Controlling_image_scaling_behavior)), but there is no help from that in other browsers. And it also removes paths smoothing.

Code extract:

```
var shapeCanvas = null;
var w = 320, h = 240;
var startTime = 0;

function start() {
    startTime = Date.now();
    var docCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    . . .
    shapeCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    . . .
    drawShape(shapeCanvas.getContext('2d'));

    drawNext(docCanvas.getContext('2d'));
}

function drawNext(ctx) {
    var msec = (Date.now() - startTime);
    var time = msec / 1000; // seconds passed from start
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    ctx.save();
    // the lines to change: time | (time * 10) | Math.floor(time * 10)
    ctx.translate((time < 500) ? Math.floor(time * 10) : 500,
                  (time < 500) ? Math.floor(time * 10) : 500);
    ctx.drawImage(shapeCanvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();

    __nextFrame(function() {
       drawNext(ctx);
    });
}

function drawShape(ctx) {
    . . .
}
```

Comment: The path is rendered on `shapeCanvas` with anti-aliasing.  When you draw an image with antialiasing onto a canvas at a non-integer location, you get anti-aliasing on top of anti-aliasing.  The pulsating blurry edge of the stroke becomes thickest when drawing the image halfway between integer pixel locations and vanishes when drawing the image exactly on integer pixel locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the tutorial in your first link.

Just to clear the air:

```
shapeCanvas.style.width = w + 'px';
shapeCanvas.style.height = h + 'px';
```

is not really worth doing. No point setting the style if its just a in-memory canvas, and you shouldn't really ever want to set the width and height *style* of a canvas anyway, it just confounds things.

What ellisbben said in the comment is pretty much what's happening.

It's possible to get around it in a few hackish ways I bet. One way might be to make sure its never drawn on an integer pixel. Another might be to use `ctx.scale(.99,.99)` before drawing anything so it is always anti-aliased. It's tough to get a consistent solution here because different browswer's implementations of anti-aliasing are different.

Here are a few experiments from myself:

http://jsfiddle.net/KYZYT/29/

The first two are the shape drawn from a canvas and also drawn from a PNG

The second two are the same pair but scaled by `.99,.99`

The last one is the real thing. It still blurs a bit but looks a lot sharper than using the images.

None of my experiments lead to an end of your pulsating, at least not on a microscopic level. I think this is just something you're going to have to live with if you want to animate pixel-perfect images onto half-pixel spaces.

If you really feel you can't just draw on perfect pixels then your (second) best bet for consistency is probably to find a way to force anti-aliasing at all times. Making sure you are always translated to a non-integer or scaling it ever so slightly are decent candidates, but there may be others.

To be honest, you best bet is to not cache these animated paths until you absolutely need the performance from them. Cache the stylized buttons and other static things you make, but if you've got animated paths that need to move slowly and precisely and look very good, you might as well stick with the true thing over my caching optimization unless you *really* need it for those too.

Comment: Upvote for: 1) discouraging style width and height 2) discouraging caching.

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer is the most detailed.

At least now I know now that the problem is not in my code and, besides, it was an interesting experiment). May be I'll get rid of such way of caching, I need to think some more time on it.

Comment: I think my method of caching is great if you have static things like fancy buttons that get redrawn over and over with the scene. But for movable objects its a major question of performance/looks that you can only really answer very late in your application development.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shameless plug but: I've implement smooth animation in HTML5 slot game with bit hacky way. The generated cached Image is drawn on small canvas once and then I used translate3d() with  -moz-transform / -webkit-transform  styles for the canvas to move, mirror and scale the image around.

Pregeneration

1. Create Image
2. Draw image content
3. Create canvas object in DOM

Animation phase

1. Clear canvas
2. Draw the cached image to the canvas
3. Use CSS3 transforms (scale3d and translate3d) to move canvas around.